# is google volley singleton really thread safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley

In the android tranning [Use a Singleton Pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton)

```
public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

I'm thinking it still not thread safey.
If `Object A` do `getInstance` and `Object B` do `getInstance` synchronously,it will still break the lock, and create two mInstance.
Because `synchronized` for method is only available for ONE object from different thread, but not for 2 objects.

**So DO I have wrong comprehension, or below code is more safe than original?**

```
public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
  synchronized(MySingleton.class) 
  { 
     if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
     }
  }
    return mInstance;
}
```

Comment: it is not more safe than original. `synchronized` allows only on thread at time to execute the method.

Comment: As this is a static method, the synchronization lock will not use an instance of the class, but the class itself. Synchronized static methods **work**.

Comment: Also consider some double-check locking explanations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: Your two examples do exactly the same thing.  A `static synchronized` method of class `Foo` is the same as a `static` method whose entire body is wrapped in a `synchronized(Foo.class)` block.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples do exactly the same thing.

This:

```
class Foobar {
    static synchronized mumble(...) { doSomething(); }
}
```

Is just a shorthand way to write:

```
class Foobar {
    static mumble(...) { 
        synchronized(Foobar.class) { doSomething(); }
    }
}
```

A similar rule applies for non-static methods.  This:

```
class Foobar {
    synchronized mumble(...) { doSomething(); }
}
```

is just a shorthand way to write:

```
class Foobar {
    mumble(...) { 
        synchronized(this) { doSomething(); }
    }
}
```

---

I'm not sure I really understand your question, but maybe you do have "wrong comprehension".

I don't like the shortcut forms because synchronized *methods* draw attention away from the fact that methods are not what we want to protect with synchronization.  What we want to protect is *data*.

We use synchronization when it is impossible for one thread to update some collection of data without creating a temporary, invalid state that other threads must not be allowed to see.  We wrap a `synchronized` block around the code that creates the invalid state, and we also wrap `synchronized` blocks that synchronize on the *same object* around every piece of code that must not be allowed to see the invalid state.

The JVM will never allow two threads to be synchronized on the same object at the same time, so if we've done everything right, no thread will be allowed to see the invalid state except for the one that temporarily creates it.